# 3D CNN Unmathcing result with saved model on local vs Nimblebox

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have saved the model trained on my personal laptop (with Nvidia GPU). I got val accuracy of 0.85. If I load the same saved model in personal laptop and evaluate it on val data, I get consistent results. I tried multiple times and I get consistent results.

But, when I upload this model to Nimblebox and evaluate on val data, I get accuracy as 0.52. Can anyone explain what could cause this difference ?

I use below code:

```
model_path = 'model_init_2020-12-2511_49_09.401932/model-00063-0.38162-0.88537-0.55922-0.85000.h5'

import keras
loaded_model2 = keras.models.load_model(model_path) #Load Model
validator_generator = generator(val_path, val_doc, 100) #Load Validation Data
data, labels = next(validator_generator) #Assign Data and Labels
loaded_model2.evaluate(data, labels) #Evaluate the model
```

Results on Local:

```
Results:
100/100 [==============================] - 2s 19ms/step
[0.5561962187290191, 0.85]
```

But on Nimblebox, the loss is higher and accuracy is 0.52.

I have verified that the package versions and code (hyperparams etc.) is same on both environments. Data is also same.

Also, I can replicate it the other way as well. If I download a trained model from Nimblebox, load it locally and run it, the results vary but only slightly (0.70 to 0.68 etc).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is from  the issue [model.save and load giving different result](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4875#issuecomment-296696536) on keras

This issue might be because keras uses tf.global_variable_initializer which means that it will reinitialize the weights before saving them there is a flag _MANUAL_VAR_INIT in the tensorflow backend which you can turn on by doing this before training your model.

```
from keras.backend import manual_variable_initialization manual_variable_initialization(True)
```

And the other way would be to just save the weights and not the whole architecture and just load the weights by using `load_weights` instead of `load_model`.

And we have a helpful community for helping with such issues.
[NimbleBox Community](https://community.nimblebox.ai/)

Aakash from
NimbleBox.ai

Comment: Thanks. I will try with only weights.